# Lightbox not opening due to smooth scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox

I'm trying to implement a CSS only lightbox effect for some certificates on my personal site.  Unfortunately, whenever I click the image that I would like to expand, it either scrolls to the top of the page, or just a little bit down - instead of targeting the full size image (I believe this is due to the smooth scrolling logic confusing the hashmark in the image target with the hashmark in the page target).  I can only access the expanded image by manually typing the address in the browser.  Any suggestions??

[Here is the site link.](https://www.justincefai.co)

[image]

[image]

```html
    <div class="background-certs" id="certificates">  
  <div class="title-box">
    <h3 class="h3-web">{ certificates }</h3>
    <h4 class="h4-web">I enjoy learning</h4>
  </div>    

  <div class="cert-container">
    <a href="#cert-item-1" class="button-new">
      <div class="box1 grid-sub">
          <%= image_tag "firehose.jpg", class: "full-width-cert" %>
      </div>
      </a>
    <h4 class="h4-subtitle">software engineering bootcamp</h4>
    <p class="cert-subtitle">Dec. 2017 - Oct. 2018</p> 
  </div>

  <div class="cert-container">
    <a href="#cert-item-2" class="button-new">
      <div class="box1 grid-sub">
        <%= image_tag "udemy-js.jpg", class: "full-width-cert" %>
      </div>
    </a>  
    <h4 class="h4-subtitle">JavaScript: the weird parts</h4>
    <p class="cert-subtitle">Nov. 2018</p> 
  </div>

    <br class="clear" />

    <div class="cert-container">
      <a href="#cert-item-3" class="button-new">
        <div class="box1 grid-sub">
          <%= image_tag "udemy-algos.jpg", class: "full-width-cert" %>
        </div>
      </a> 
      <h4 class="h4-subtitle">algorithms + data structures</h4>
      <p class="cert-subtitle">Dec. 2018</p> 
    </div>

    <div class="cert-container">
      <a href="#cert-item-4" class="button-new">
        <div class="box1 grid-sub">
          <%= image_tag "udemy-shopify.jpg", class: "full-width-cert" %>
        </div>
      </a>
      <h4 class="h4-subtitle">shopify themes from scratch</h4>
      <p class="cert-subtitle">Feb. 2019</p> 
    </div>


    <div class="certificate-lightboxes">

      <div class="cert-lightbox" id="cert-item-1">
        <div class="cert-lightbox__content">
          <a href="#certificates" class="close"></a>
          <%= image_tag "firehose.jpg", class: "full-width-cert" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cert-lightbox" id="cert-item-2">
        <div class="cert-lightbox__content">
          <a href="#certificates" class="close"></a>
          <%= image_tag "udemy-js.jpg", class: "full-width-cert" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cert-lightbox" id="cert-item-3">
        <div class="cert-lightbox__content">
        <a href="#certificates" class="close"></a>
          <%= image_tag "udemy-algos.jpg", class: "full-width-cert" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cert-lightbox" id="cert-item-4">
        <div class="cert-lightbox__content">
          <a href="#certificates" class="close"></a>
          <%= image_tag "udemy-shopify.jpg", class: "full-width-cert" %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
  </div>
```

```css
/** LIGHTBOX MARKUP **/

.cert-lightbox {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  transition: transform ease-in-out 100ms;
}

.cert-lightbox:target {
  transform: scale(1, 1) !important;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 900;
}

.cert-lightbox__content {
  width: 65%;
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background: red;
  top: -1em;
  right: -1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.close::after {
  content: "X";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

smooth scroll in application.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $root = $('html, body');

$('a[href^="#"]').click(function () {
$root.animate({
    scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 400);

return false;
  });
  </script>
```

smooth scroll in scroll.js

```
 function scrollToHash(event) {
// On-page links
if (
  location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
  && 
  location.hostname == this.hostname
) {
  // Figure out element to scroll to
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
  // Does a scroll target exist?
  if (target.length) {
    // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000, function() {
      // Callback after animation
      // Must change focus!
      var $target = $(target);
      $target.focus();
      if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
        return false;
      } else {
        $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
        $target.focus(); // Set focus again
      };
    });
  }
}
};

  // Select all links with hashes
 $('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
   .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(scrollToHash);
```

Comment: Where does smooth scrolling come into this? I don’t see anything related to smooth scrolling in the code you posted. On your site you linked, there is no lightbox on that section of the page and no smooth scrolling (in Firefox on macOS), so I can’t test it either.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane the smooth scrolling is set up to either scroll up or down to a target with a hashmark.  Since the targets for the lightbox are #cert-item-1, #cert-item-2 etc., I think for some reason when I click the image to "open" the lightbox, it instead activates the scroll effect.  I only linked my site so you can access the JS code for the scroll on the down arrow on the main page, and the back to top arrow on the contact page via Chrome DevTools.  I went ahead and pushed the changes live to my site, so you should be able to access the lightbox code now.  Thanks for checking it out!

Comment: That description helps. I think the solution would be to edit how your smooth scrolling or lightbox libraries are set up – either add configuration to the JavaScript that sets them up to force only the lightbox to handle those links, or switch libraries to a more configurable one. If you want help with that, edit your question to include the JavaScript that initializes those libraries. Make sure it’s clear which libraries you are using.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Thanks, the question has been edited.  So I tried to edit the scrollToHash function to ignore the certificate targets with no luck.  I added additional lines to the bottom of the function under .not('[href="#"]'), with .not('[href="#cert-item-1"]') and so on.  I'll continue poking around for a solution, if you have any suggestions I'm all ears!

Comment: You aren't using a doctype and are in "quirks mode" where no one should be since 1999 at least. Until you properly insert a doctype, which just might change all the work you've done, you will continue to have ongoing issues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because he is in quirks mode without a doctype and will have ongoing issues until this, and the ensuing problems, are resolved.

Comment: @JustinCefai To add a [doctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Doctype) to a page, just insert `<!DOCTYPE html>` before the initial `<html>` tag. If you’re using Rails, putting it at the top of `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` will ensure that all your pages have a doctype.

Comment: @Rob Doctype has been added.  This is this first I've heard of quirks mode, so thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Well, since you claim to be " a FULL STACK Web Developer", you should know how to debug your website, it is full of js errors.

Comment: @Janis I am a full stack web developer.  I didn't claim to know how to solve every issue that I encounter, which is why I brought the question here - so I can learn from more experienced developers.  I do this fully knowing that there will be people like yourself that will offer absolutely zero help whatsoever and point out that I'm inexperienced.  Why?  Because there are people like Rory that will help, and I've learned a lot from them.

Comment: @Janis Here's a better way to word your comment - "You have a lot of JS errors on your site that you should look into.  For example A) B) C) etc.  This article might help." - See how easy that is?  I can overcome some rookie mistakes, and you can help someone out.  Way cooler than being pretentious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Avoiding attaching smooth scroll listeners to links with an attribute

As a slight improvement over adding multiple `.not` calls like `.not('[href="#cert-item-1"]')` to your smooth scroll initialization, you could add a custom HTML attribute `data-no-smooth-scroll` to each of your lightbox links ([about `data-` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)):

```html
<div class="cert-container">
  <a href="#cert-item-1" data-no-smooth-scroll class="button-new"> <!-- added on this line -->
    <div class="box1 grid-sub">
      <%= image_tag "firehose.jpg", class: "full-width-cert" %>
    </div>
  </a>
  <h4 class="h4-subtitle">software engineering bootcamp</h4>
  <p class="cert-subtitle">Dec. 2017 - Oct. 2018</p> 
</div>

<!-- also add the attribute within the `a` for #cert-item-2, etc. -->
```

Then only a single `.not` is needed in the JavaScript:

```js
// Select all links with hashes
$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .not('[data-no-smooth-scroll]') // this line was added
  .click(scrollToHash);
```

The selector `[data-no-smooth-scroll]` is a [Has Attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).

### Removing smooth scroll listeners when setting up the lightbox

Alternatively, you could change your lightbox initialization code to call `.off('click')` (assuming that it uses jQuery – you didn’t show that code). This will remove any existing `click` event listeners from the selected links before attaching the new `click` event listeners that open a lightbox.

This would be cleaner in some ways, but it would introduce a requirement that the lightboxes be initialized *after* the smooth scrolling. Also, if you ever added another global click handler such as Google Analytics, it would remove that handler too. So I worry that this solution would be hard to keep working as the code is changed in the future.

Comment: Still no luck after implementing the doctype and making the changes that you suggested, but I really do appreciate all of the help.  The lightbox is CSS only.  I wanted to avoid using any unnecessary JS, but maybe that's the best option?  I went ahead and pushed the changes anyway so you can check it out if you're still up for it.